# How do I install Divergence IV - "A New Hope"?

Tags: appearance

i found that ubuntu is quite tacky so i found Divergence IV - "A New Hope". i tried but cannot install it.

How do i install it, please give clear simple steps as i am just a basic user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this link - http://ubuntu-art.org/content/show.php/Divergence+IV+-+%22A+New+Hope%22?content=133892 - there's a good installation instruction...

Comment: this doesn't work anymore. it does not work for ubuntu 13.04

Comment: I have done it an another way I installed the theme file into emerald. Then I pressed alt f2 then pressed emerald replace. How do I set the emerald theme as the one that it uses.